# CSS Animations not working?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to just do a simple animation where I change a box's color. However, the box never appears, and obviously no animation happens. I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
<div>
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:myfirst 5s;
-moz-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Opera */
</div>

@keyframes myfirst
{
from {background:red;}
to {background:yellow;}
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
{
from {background:red;}
to {background:yellow;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {background:red;}
to {background:yellow;}
}

@-o-keyframes myfirst /* Opera */
{
from {background:red;}
to {background:yellow;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 ....
</body>
</html>
```

Why does nothing happen? I'm not really a web developer, but thought I would give this as shot. I seem to have followed all instructions properly, but perhaps I missed something.

As a note, everything here is done locally, this is just in a .html file on my desktop. But it seems like it should still work. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can validate even local files through the W3C (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) which is a great first step to debugging web code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just having a bad day, but you have

```
<style>
<div>
    VARIOUS CSS RULES
```

You should write it as

```
<style>
div {
/* snip */
<body>
<div>....</div>
```

Seems to work though: http://jsfiddle.net/CPL6P/

Comment: That's what I missed. I didn't know the <div> </div> was necessary after the body, thanks a ton. You saved me a lot more aggravation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
<div>
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:myfirst 5s;
-moz-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Opera */
</div>
```

should be

```
<style>
div {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:myfirst 5s;
-moz-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: I realized that, however, it did not help. I'm getting a bunch of syntax errors in the keyframes section. Realize anything else amiss?

Comment: the errors should be based on the fact that you have multiple browser rules specified and any one browser will show the other 2 as errors as it wont recognise them, but if you make the changes above, everything should work as expected. at least in chrome and ie9 (all i have tested)